# How to setup a ubuntu home network based on a powerful server and many outdated laptops as terminals?

Tags: server, command-line, xorg, home-server

I am wondering if it is easy to do this. I know that using X to serve the other computers ain't that difficult. I just have no idea how would I have to configure the laptops in order for them to work as terminals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your older laptops can boot from their network cards (ie. PXE boot) then you can set up LTSP, which is fully supported in Ubuntu:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuLTSP

Comment: That's wonderful. Do you think I'd be able to make Skype work on the thin clients?

Comment: Absolutely, people do this sort of things in call centers all the time. LTSP has been around forever, you'll find tons of information there on how to do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pretty old post which I wrote: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1437074

You will have to copy commands line by line from the script cause from 10.04 it doesn't work any more automatically by dropping into the Terminal this script.

Comment: it would be great if you could put that entire post in here so we can keep it updated over time!